# Downsizing a Texture2D in XNA

Tags: xna, collision-detection, scale, texture2d, downsize

I would like to downsize a Texture2D object to another Texture2D object in XNA.

The reason is to use the downsized object for pixel based collision detection.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [per-pixel collision tutorial](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/tutorial/collision2dperpixel) as well as the [transformed per-pixel collision tutorial](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/tutorial/collision2dperpixeltransformed).

Essentially, to do collision detection on a transformed texture (such as a scaled one like you want) you use a [transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) [matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.aspx). It's not overly difficult and the tutorials give a good example. The tutorial doesn't scale but rotates, but comments are include in the source that show you where and how to do scaled as well.